# Ektron Search Error-Invalid Uri

Tags: asp.net, ektron

In ektron while executing this code

```
SearchResponseData[] result= search.Search(requestData,HttpContext.Current,ref resultCount);
```

The below error is showing

"Invalid URI: The URI is empty."

From where this URI comes?

Comment: first of all, what version of ektron are you running?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have not installed/have not correctly configured your search provider.

Verify that your FAST/Search Server Express/SOLR configuration is correct. These are independent from Ektron and will need to have been installed previously.

If you have not attached a search provider, then follow the steps at:
http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v85/webhelp/Navigating/Search85/config%20CMS%20and%20ss%20remotely.htm
to use Ektron's search configuration utility.